# PrimeVue/PrimeFace: component's 'optionLabel' as a function?

Tags: vue.js, primevue

Some of PrimeVue/PrimeFace's components have an `optionLabel` that adds a label to each option of a list/select. Such as in, e.g.:

```
<Listbox :options="cities" optionLabel="name" />
```

In this case `name` must be field of the objects in `cities`. But the documentation also states that this can be a function:

```
optionLabel: Property name or getter function to use as the label of an option.
```

But I can find no example of what this function should look like. I can make it a function, but that only gets called once for the complete `listbox` component, not for each option within it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Just like in Vue, you can reference a local function from `methods` or `computed` ot just use plain JavaScript

```js
<template>
...
  <Listbox :options="cities" :optionLabel="name" />
<!-- OR --> 
  <Listbox :options="cities" :optionLabel="cities.name" />
...
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    name() {
      return 'name';
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The function receives the option as a parameter. So here, the options will be displayed as:

> - New York (NY)
> - Connecticut (CT)

```
<template>
    <Listbox :options="cities" :optionLabel="display" />
</template>

<script setup>
    const cities = [
        { name: 'New York', code: 'NY' },
        { name: 'Connecticut', code: 'CT' },
    ]
    const display = (city) => city.name + ' (' + city.code + ')'
</script>
```